# Double text selection in code editor of Qt Creator

Tags: qt-creator

How to make a double (triple) text selection in Qt Creator Code Editor, the same as is after inserting **code snippet** from **Parameters** menu, which will allow me to do edit simutaneously in different places?

For example: After inserting **for** snippet

```
for (int ***index*** = 0; ***index*** < count; ++***index***) {
}
```

I can change ***index***, and it'll be changed in other places of **for**s declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Qt Editor you can change names of variables, classes, functions, etc. with the Refactor option [*Rename Symbol*](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-refactoring.html#renaming-symbols). It allows you to change it at all places in one step.

You can activate it through:

- either right mouse > Refactor > Rename Symbol Under Cursor;
- or in the menu: Tools > C++ >  Rename Symbol Under Cursor;
- or Shift-Ctrl-R.

---

Edit: 
In the case of the text not being a 'symbol' (variable/class/etc.)
the best option would be Find/Replace to simultaneously change certain text. However to limit it to lines in which the variable is in a `for` heading you would need a regular expression, which makes it a bit more complex.

For example for:

```
void func1() {   
    for(int index=0; index<10; index++) {
        //some code...
    }
}

void func2()
{    
    for(int index=0; index<10; index++) {
        \\code
    }
}
```

You could use the Regular expression:

```
for\s*\(\s*(\w+)\s+index([^;]*);\s*index([^;]*);\s+index(.*)\)
```

and replace it with:

```
for(\1 i\2; i\3; i\4)
```

Which results in:

```
void func1() {   
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        //some code...
    }
}

void func2()
{    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        \\code
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know it. But snippets code insertions allow to edit abstract pieces of text, not only variables or class names, and that is much more convient sometimes. However, thank you.

Comment: Ok. Exactly, I can do it in that manner. It'll be useful. And regular expressions as well. Thank you!